# security issue nodejs port 4000

Tags: node.js, security, express, port

I am running nodejs (express framework) on port 3000 and works fine. Accidentally, I ran the program on port 4000 and I saw all of my data could be revealed like ftp. the interesting part is that just for port 4000 this happens and in my app I am just listening on port 3000

http://localhost:4000

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viyRz.png)

Comment: What are you running on port 4000? It seems a webserver that has your nodejs application's folder as web directory. So, change the configuration of what you're running on port 4000, or move your nodejs application in another folder.

Comment: Thanks Federkun. I thin you are correct but how can I get what application is using this port ?

Comment: It is very strange. I have used  netstat -a -n -o | find "4000" command and I got:  UDP    192.168.0.180:64000    *:*     3972.  I closed nodejs and re-run it and still I see this UDP with PID 3972 is active but localhost:4000 returns no page anymore. Do you have any advice? Thanks

Comment: Could it be this related to GIT? I have installed GIT already but I do not know the usage of it yet

Comment: What process is running with PID 3972?

Comment: Nothing actually. Just I could see IP of my internet service providers for such PIDs rather than any application